# Query Minecraft(Bukkit) Server Javascript Auto-Updating

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, minecraft, bukkit

I have a client who wants me to design them a website; and they would like a player display for each of their servers that updates every five seconds or so. How would I go about doing this? I have an example below; any help would be appreciated.

http://secure.swag-craft.net/mcstatus_v1/

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript to refresh the page automatically

```
setTimeout('location.reload(true);', 5000);
```

Comment: First of all, you don't even need Javascript to refresh a page after 5 seconds, you can use a meta tag for that. Secondly, I'm sure there is a better way of calling and retrieving the data other than refreshing a page.